# Using enhanced for loop to print inputs from user and update variable

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

Whenever the inputs for the my static variable total are entered by the user it will not update by adding the next input to it using +=, instead it seems to add the two together giving me double the amount. I thought of using a regular for loop under the enhanced for loop to iterate the static variable but I that did not work either.

```
    while(isRunning) {
      try {
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of your item you want to add: (type quit to exit) ");
          String item = input.nextLine();

        if(item.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
          break;
        }
        System.out.println("Please enter the price of the item to be added to the invoice. ");
          receipt.setTotal(input.nextDouble());
          input.nextLine();
          itemList itemlist = new itemList(item, Invoice.total);
          price.add(itemlist);

      } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception caught!");
      }

      for(Invoice itemization : price) {
        Invoice.total += itemization.getTotal();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Item: " + itemization.getItem() + "\nPrice: " + itemization.getTotal());
        System.out.println("Subtotal: " + Math.round(receipt.getTotal() * 100.00) / 100.00);

}



import java.util.*;

public class Invoice {

  static Double total;
  public String item;
  List<Invoice> price = new ArrayList<>();

  public String getItem() {
    return item;
  }

  public double getTotal() {
    return total;
  }

  public void setTotal(Double total) {
    Invoice.total = total;
  }

  public void endBalance() {

    if (getTotal() > 0.0) {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("$" + getTotal() + " Will be deposited once cleared. ");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Expect most transfer to deposit to your account with 3 to 5 business days. ");
    System.out.println();

    } else {
      System.out.println("Available balance too low for bank deposit. ");
    }
  }

  // @Override
  // public String toString() {
  // //   return receipt.toString;
  // }
}

class itemList extends Invoice {

  public itemList(String item, Double total) {
    this.item = item;



  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As `Invoice`'s `getTotal()` method returns the value of the static variable,
`Invoice.total += itemization.getTotal();` is effectively a `Invoice.total *= 2;`.
What did you expect?

Comment: What would it need to return I thought the getter always returned the variable?

Comment: As I don't know what you want to achieve, I cannot advise what you should do.

Comment: I do not want it to return the the static variable Invoice.total *= 2 but add the loop variable itemization.getTotal() to the static variable in each loop. += each time it iterates.

Comment: I think that your data model shouldn't have a static variable `total` with getters and setters on instances.

Comment: Yeah that's the conclusion I am beginning to come to. Causes too many issues and conflicts

Comment: It's just inconsistent. If you want it to be a property of each `Invoice` instance, make it a (non-`static`) instance field. If you want it to be an overall value for all `Invoice`s, make setter and getter `static` as well.